# Flowplayer - movie URL as redirect

Tags: php

Is it possible to define URL which is redirect to movie?

I tried like that:

```
    $f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
    clip:  {
        url:'http://my-page.com/movies/bb.php',
        provider: 'lighttpd',
        autoPlay: false,
        autoBuffering: true
    },
    plugins: {
        lighttpd: {
            url: "flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.13.swf",
            queryString: escape('?start=${start}')
            }
    }   

});
```

And bb.php:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily"); 
header("Location: http://file.com/file.flv);
exit;
```

But it doesn't work. Flowplaer get error: "Stream not found".

Is it possible to make this redirect?

Comment: It should be possible - are you sure the file you're redirecting to is there?

Comment: OMG, my misstake. I forgot about dot and script generated an error. Everything is OK, sorry.